# If in a Triangle ABC b , c , B ( where A ,B ,C denotes angles and a , b ,c denotes sides of the triangle ABC ) are given and b < c . Prove that

Tags: triangles

If in  a Triangle ABC    b , c ,  B  ( where A ,B ,C  denotes angles  and  a,b,c denotes sides of the triangle ABC ) are given and b < c prove that $$ \ sin \frac  {(A_1-A_2)} {2}\ = \frac { (a_1-a_2)} {(2b)}   $$

MY ATTEMPT :

taking cosine rule $$ cos B = \frac{\ a^2 + c^2 - b^2} {2ac} $$  and  rearranging the terms we get $${a^2 -2ac cosB +(c^2-b^2)} = 0 $$    taking $ a_1 $ and $a_2$ as roots and solving $ a_1 $ + $a_2$ = $ 2c$ $cos B$ and  $a_1$ $a_2$ = $ c^2$ - $b^2$   we get $$  ( a_1 -  a_2  )^2  =  4b^2 -4c^2 cos^2 B $$

I am  struck here please help me to solve this question

Comment: It is not clear what $A_1$, $A_2$ etc. is. Can you clarify by using $A$, $B$, $C$ for angles and $a$, $b$, $c$ for corresponding facing sides?

Comment: @mf67 I think it means the two possible length of $A$ as $b,c,B$ does not define one triangle but two possible triangles .

Comment: I do not think it is correct unless I have understood the question wrong. What is true is $\ sin  {\frac{A_1-A_2} {2}} = \frac { (a_1-a_2)} {(2b)}$

Comment: Actually I think the result is wrong. The result only holds when $C=30^{\circ}$ https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYF8y.png

Comment: Given $\angle B$ is fixed and so are sides $b, c$, you get two values of $A$ when the side opposite $B$ is equal to $b$. It is possible because $b \lt c$. There will be values of $b, c, B$ that will give you a right angled triangle and then $A_1 - A_2 = 0$ but that is a special case.

Comment: @MathLover thanks for your comment I have typed the question wrong sorry for inconvenience

Comment: OK, so are you ok now or do you need help?

Comment: I still  need help

Comment: OK @cr001 just posted. That's pretty much!

Comment: cant we solve it manually by using cosine rule and other formulae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

As shown in the picture, $BC=a_1, BC'=a_2, \theta = {A_1 - A_2\over 2}$.

Therefore $\sin({A_1 - A_2\over 2}) = {{a_1-a_2\over 2}\over b}$ by definition of sine function in right triangle.

Comment: thanks but cant we solve it manually I mean  by using cosine rule etc

Comment: @victor ${\sin(A_1)\over \sin(B)}= {a_1\over b}$ and ${\sin(A_2)\over \sin(B)}= {a_2\over b}$ so ${\sin(A_1)-\sin(A_2)\over 2\sin(B)}={a_1-a_2\over 2b}$. You can then use the formula $\sin(A_1)-\sin(A_2)=2\sin({A_1-A_2\over 2})\cos({A_1+A_2\over 2})$ and show $\cos({A_1+A_2\over 2})=\sin(B)$. But this is way too complicated compared to the geometric method.